# Use 'get' form action within a WordPress plugin admin page

Tags: plugin-development, admin

I am writing a WordPress plugin that has a dashboard URL like this...

```
http://www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin.php
```

I have a datepicker box within the page that I use to select a date then click submit like this...

```
<form action="http://www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin.php" method="get">
<input type="text" class="mydatepicker" name="start_date" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I am expecting the page to reload with a URL like this...

```
http://www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin.php?start_date=2014-04-03
```

But instead i get this...

```
http://www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?start_date=2014-04-03
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please stop misusing the tag [tag:wordpress.org]. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this code,

```
<form action="http://www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="my-plugin.php" />
<input type="text" class="mydatepicker" name="start_date" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

This will show the url like this...

```
http://www.mydomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-plugin.php&start_date=2014-04-03
```

Check and let me know your comments, if it works

Comment: Okay Great.. Please mark it as resolved. So others will get help from this

Comment: You save my day. This should be documented in the codex....

Answer (score 0):

Your page reference is held in `$_REQUEST['page']` so rather than hard coding your plugin page, use that.

Comment: Where is anything hard coded? Aside from that, this is more a comment as it doesn't explain what helps _solving_ the problem.

Comment: You're correct on the comment part, apologies; What I'm saying is don't use http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php in action field use the value from $_REQUEST['page'] then your page will be poertable to any domain.

Comment: Please file an [edit] and show a full example (probably best with included validation). You may want to take a look at the [help] and see how to write a good answer as yours was auto flagged as _low quality_ :)